# How To Get ID of Order Deleted from Shopify Webhook - Laravel & Shopify

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, webhooks

In my tutorial, I realised that I am able to get the number/id of the order during every event except `orders/delete`. In my controller below, I try to retrieve the order number just as I do for every topic `('orders/create', 'orders/paid')etc`, but then I get an error saying:

> Undefined index: number in Controller

**Controller**

```
  public function registerOrderDeleteWebhook()
    {
             $shop = Auth::user()->site;
            $token = Auth::user()->access_token;
            $shopify = Shopify::setShopUrl($shop)->setAccessToken($token);
            Shopify::setShopUrl($shop)->setAccessToken($token)->post("admin/webhooks.json", ['webhook' => 
             ['topic' => 'orders/delete',
             'address' => 'https://example.domain.com/order-delete-webhook',
             'format' => 'json'
             ]
            ]);
    }



public function orderDeleteWebhook(Request $request)
 {
        $order = $request->getContent();
        $order = json_decode($order, true);
        $order_id = $order['number'];

        //send notification to Admin with order number deleted below        

 }
```

Why could this be happening for only `orders/delete`?

Comment: Did you tried to dump your `$request` and `$order` variables? Can you put the portion of code where `orderDeleteWebhook` function is called?

Comment: @gomd, the portion code is already there.. When a user deletes an order on shopify, the post  request is sent to the address `https://example.domain.com/order-delete-webhook` which triggers `orderDeleteWebhook`

Comment: Ok, then, can you try to dump your `$request` and `$order` variables with `var_dump` function? In order to see if the problem is in how you make the request or how you interpret the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the undefinded index error

occurs because there is no number field in Shopify Order Delete webhook response. Moreover, it is always a good idea to check if the field exists in the first place.

If you look at the [Delete Order response](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/webhook) sent by Shopify, it only includes,

```
{
  "id": 777859760246
}
```

where id is the Order Id. But as the order is deleted you cannot get anymore details later even via API. According to [this forum post](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/order-deletion-webhook-116057) an order cannot be deleted until it is cancelled first. So a workaround is to listen to Order Cancel hook too and save this information somwehere in your Laravel application ( database etc ) and use it later when Order Delete webhook is recieved.